# How can I get a large amount of Ethereum transactions in a database without running my own node? Does a database like this exist already?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blocks, database

I am doing research into Ethereum transactions and I simply need a database of 1000 transactions or just about 10 blocks worth of transactions. What is the easiest and fastest way to acquire this?

Do I have to setup and run my own node or can I just download this from somewhere?

**All I need is a database that has transactions for my research.**

Comment: Google used to provide blockchains in a BigQuery dataset.

Comment: I checked it out and I found a solution. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment led me to take a second look at Google's BigQuery dataset. I was not able to get exactly what I wanted but I found https://luabase.com/ which was pretty helpful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0DyV_tiVEI This video was a nice starting point to use luabase.